# why browser gives priority to top and left instant of right and bottom styles?

Tags: css

When i try to override an element style position top and left by setting right or bottom 
It is not working , left and top properties are only in the browser's concern and never see people use right and bottom properties where can I use the those properties efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

If there's no specified `height` or `width`, and the element in question has position `absolute` or `fixed`, then specifying both a `top` *and* `bottom` (or `left` *and* `right`) actually means something — you might want a lightbox to be 20 pixels from each edge of the body for example, and occupy all the remaining space.

However with `relative` positioning, or when other specified dimensions make the calculation impossible, then specifying distances from both edges will result in a conflict of instruction, so the browser is forced to take one over the other. `top` and `left` are the natural precedence for layout (and text in Western script), so they're taken arbitrarily.

You can however reset `top` and `left` by specifying the `auto` value, allowing your `bottom` and `right` to take precedence:

```
/* previous rules */
.thing {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

/* your rule */
.thing {
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*I try to override an element style position top and left by setting right or bottom*

Firstly you cannot override `top` and `left` properties using `right` and `bottom`

If you want to override them you need to set the values like

```
element.class {
   top: [auto, inherit, px, %];
   left: [auto, inherit, px, %];
}

/* Don't leave them blank */
```

Now am coming to the second question here.

*never see people use right and bottom properties where can I use the those properties efficiently*

Take an example where you need a button positioned to the right and bottom of the container element and the element `height` and `width` are dynamic, so in this case you need to use `right: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` as you cannot position the element from `left` and `top`, as you don't know how much `px` you need to take the element from `left` or from `top` as the element size is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `top: auto; left: auto` to override your previous setting and have it use bottom right instead.

Comment: I think he wants to prevent top and left from taking effect.