# Inline Top/Bottom Property Style Not Overriding External Stylesheet

Tags: html, css

When attempting to change the 'bottom' CSS property using inline styling the 'top' property on the external stylesheet takes precedence.

How come?

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

body {
  font-family:arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative; bottom:-100px">
test
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why browser gives priority to top and left instant of right and bottom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056179/why-browser-gives-priority-to-top-and-left-instant-of-right-and-bottom-styles)

Comment: No offense but I can barely make sense of what that guy wrote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's true that inline styles have more specificity than external styles, the difference here is that `top` and `bottom` are **different** properties. If they were the same property, **[CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)** would come into play and the inline style would override the external.

However, as `top` and `bottom` are different properties, the browser wants to apply **both** of them. Considering they have directly opposing effects on layout, only **one** of the two can be applied. Precedence is given to `top`, with `bottom` being ignored.

This is true **regardless** of if the `bottom` property has more specificity than than the `top` property!

This is clarified in **[the `top` MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)**:

> When both `top` and `bottom` are specified, *and* `height` is unspecified or either `auto` or `100%`, both the `top` and `bottom` distances are respected. In all other situations, if `height` is constrained in any way, the `top` property takes precedence and the `bottom` property is ignored.

Your scenario falls under the '*all other situations*' mentioned above.

Comment: Nice find on the MDN article!

Answer (score 0):

adding **top:auto !important;** to your inline will fix the issue.

```html
<div style="position:relative; bottom:-100px;top:auto !important;">
test
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need `!important` here. Inline styles are already more specific (and take precedence) over stylesheets. Whenever possible, avoid using `!important`

Comment: Thanks I know how to get it working, the question is more to understand _why_ the sample code does not work as expected

Comment: The main use of `!important` should be to override inline styles added by javascript. Most devs will throw it on things when they don't understand CSS precedence